# Disabled the button per each row

Tags: jquery

I have here a script getting the sum of all row inputs. What I need to do is disabled the add button per row if the to qty_total field is empty or equal to zero. Here's what I have right now http://jsfiddle.net/xt4HK/2/

Any help will appreciate.

```
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum);
});
$('.qty_total').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",false);
    } else {
    $('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Comment: set a specific 'id' or 'name' for each row!! disable all off buttons, and when each field has been changed, enable button that have specific id

Comment: in this case, your names attr are good to do that! use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4HK/7/)**

```
checkTotal();
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum);
    checkTotal();
});

function checkTotal(){
$('.qty_total').each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() === ""  || $(this).val() === 0 ) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",false);
    }
});
}
```

---

**Optimized version:** **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4HK/10/)**

```
$('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    parentTr.find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    parentTr.find('.qty_total').val(sum);

    parentTr.find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",(sum === ""  || sum === 0));

});
```

---

**Changes :**

1. Your `if()` condition was wrong, It was doing the opposite.
2. You have to check the empty condition of every blur event. You code had it just on DOM ready. So I put the condition in a common function `checkTotal()`.
3. Added condition for `value = 0`.
4. To disable/enable the button, you need to find the respective `<button>` using `$(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart')` ; and not `$('.add_to_cart')` - which would disable/enable all buttons.

Comment: I choose your optimized version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attr()` and `removeAttr()` and you need to put this each loop inside the event.

do something like this:

```
     $('.qty_total').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
```

and put this inside blur event.

or you can use `prop()` like this:

```
$('.qty_total').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",false);
    } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/L2ryV/)

[**DEMO with prop()**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/2XduG/)

Comment: `.attr("disabled", "disabled");` has compatibility issue (chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m).. use `prop` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button right in the `onblur` event handler, because if not doing so, after re-editing which makes the total empty again, the button won't be disabled.

```
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
  var sum = 0;
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
     sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum)
                       .closest('td').next()
                       .find('.add_to_cart')[0].disabled = sum == 0;

}).blur();
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/xt4HK/6/)

Comment: I dont see any downvote but @King Kong dont you see your ans a copy of others already posted below? . Your are doing exactly what other guyz posted

Comment: @Pilot all the answers here are similar, my code is totally different. The writing style, even the use of `blur()` (without argument) to trigger `onblur` initially (no one currently uses that).

Comment: I appreciate your code but I dnt downvote..+1 for your comprehensive code style..

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like:

```
//disable all add buttons on document load
$('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);

$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    var qtyEle = $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total');
    qtyEle.val(sum);    
    //check if sum exists and enable/disable accordingly
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add_to_cart").prop("disabled", !sum);    
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4HK/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `$('.qty_total').each` code insde, but you should also fix something:

```
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum);

    // put this piece inside.
    $('.qty_total').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            // prop --> attr and other change.
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').attr("disabled",false);
        } else {
            // prop --> attr and other change.
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_cart').attr("disabled",true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.qty_total').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(this).parent('tr').find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",false);
    } else {
    $(this).parent('tr').find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

if you use $('.add_to_cart'), JQuery return all element have class="add_to_cart".

Answer (score 0):

try this one, simulating change event on textbox.

```
$('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
$('.qtys').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qtys').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum).change();
});

$(document).on('change','.qty_total',function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "" || $(this).val() != 0) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",false);
    } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.add_to_cart').prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xt4HK/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.qty_total').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $('.add_to_cart').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $('.add_to_cart').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```